# Parse XCode Undefined symbols for armV7

Tags: parse-platform

I get the following errors when building my Parse project in Xcode

> : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>
> :   "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long,
>   unsigned long) const", referenced from:
>
> :       MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned
>   int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
>
> :   "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned
>   long) const", referenced from:
>
> :       MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned
>   int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
>
> :   "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
>
> :       std::vector
>
> > ::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
>
> :       std::vector
>
> > ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     MDMemoryDescriptor const&) in
> >     ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
>
> :       std::vector
>
> > ::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned
> >     long, unsigned char const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)

I am new to parse.
Please help!

Comment: Well, at least format your post! It's quite impossible to read like this. Plus, people tend to help more if you put some effort into the question...

Comment: Sorry Alex,i will fix it asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your project against `libstdc++.tbd` and `libstdc++.6.tbd` libraries to get rid of these errors.
Click on your Target and at the bottom of the General page under Linked Frameworks and Libraries click on the + sign to add these two libraries.

Comment: Thank you,Mo Nazemi! It's working now and thanks for editing my post too,i am still trying to understand this place,i will make sure to format it well next time. Thanks!